# Can all the roots of $ax^5+bx^2+c=0$, with real coefficients and $a,c\neq0$, be real numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, quintics

> Let $ax^5+bx^2+c=0$ and $a,c\neq 0$ and $a,b,c$ are real numbers.
> Can all the roots of this quintic equation be real numbers?

I divided each side by $a$ and I got

$$x^5+\frac bax^2+\frac ca=0$$

Using trial and error, I found at most $3$ roots are real numbers.For example,

$$x^5+7x^2-3=0$$

I couldn't find the case, so that $5$ roots are real numbers.

Comment: So you know Calculus?

Comment: @jjagmath A bit. But, this is not my homework. All the answer will appreciated.

Comment: Hint : Rolle's theorem. Consider the third derivate

Comment: @Peter I found the third derivative then?

Comment: For a different way, let the roots be $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$. Because the equation has no degree four term, Vieta's relations tell us that $\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=0$. Because the equation has no cubic term either, Vietar's relations also tell us that $\sum_{1\le i<j\le 5}x_ix_j=0$. Therefore the sum of the squares
$$\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^2=(\sum_{i=1}^5x_i)^2-2(\sum_{1\le i<j\le 5}x_ix_j)=0.$$
Can you conclude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes $a,b,c$ are real numbers. [If they can be arbitrary complex nothing can be said.] Using DeCarte's rule of signs, it can have at most two positive zeroes, and also at most two negative zeroes. Since you assume $a,c \neq 0$ it does not admit zero itself as a zero. Simply using the DeCarte's rule this gives at most 4, however it cannot have exactly 4 since the complex roots come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: +1 Thanks. So my conclusion is correct, right? At most $3$ real roots.

Comment: We can't use Descarte's Rule of Signs in this case because there are zero coeficients for powers 4 and 3 of x. That is why the OP found 3 real roots whereas if we try to apply the rule we would find only 1 real root.

Comment: @NoChance You are incorrect. see here note "not counting zero coefficients". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs You are also wrong about 1 root, Descartes only speaks about positive roots.

Comment: @user1094359 Since you say you used "rial and error" it seems you just tried a lot of examples. That is not an argument for the truth of a statement, so I don't know what you mean by "my conclusion" being correct. If you include an argument as to why there *cannot* be five real roots then one can judge whether the conclusion is correct.

Comment: The wiki link you have provided says "The rule states that if the nonzero terms of a single-variable polynomial with real coefficients are ordered...". Notice the words: "nonzero terms". Also, in the same wiki, the rule can be used to determine negative roots. OP has actually found 3 roots.

Comment: @NoChance To settle this: According to you, how many sign changes does $5x^{10} - 4x^6 +3x^4 -2$ have? I say it has three sign changes: one from $5$ to $-4,$ another from $-4$ to $3,$ and one from $3$ to $-2.$ The missing (or present if filled in) zero coefficients have no effect on the count of sign changes. Also the count of sign changes for any real coefficient polynomial is a completely unambiguous non-negative integer. It seems that what you're suggesting is that the count will be ambiguous in case a polynomial has missing terms (= terms with coefficient 0).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Maybe I need to look into this further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141403/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-nochance).

Comment: Thank you much for your invitation to help me. Right now I am not well, and apologize. I appreciate your effort to explain.

Comment: It's spelled [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) after the same guy who gave us cartesian coordinates. But that's an aside. The claim is actually still true even if we allow complex coefficients. That's because the sum of the squares of the zeros of this quintic is zero, see my comment under the question. Of course, for the purposes of this question allowing complex coefficients is kinda pointless and your argument is fine (+1).

Answer (score 2):

The derivative has two roots, so the function has two extrema, so it has at most three roots.

Comment: Thanks I appreciated.

Comment: Interesting observation, is there an reference for this rule?

Comment: @NoChance Which rule?

Comment: The fact that if the derivative of a function has N roots --> Function has N extremes.

Comment: @NoChance The study of extrema (not extremes) it's the most basic application of the concept of derivative. So the reference would be "any Calculus book".

Comment: Fair, thank you.

Comment: Rolle's theorem FTW,+1.